# Output all dates for a date range

Tags: python, datetime

I have a starting date (lets say January 5th 2014) and an end date (lets say July 10th 2014). I know that an event occurs every Wednesday. Is there an easy way in Python to output all Wednesday with date between those date ranges?

So assuming January 7th is a Wednesday, then the code snippet would output 01.07.2014, 01.14.2014, 01.21.2014, and so on.

Comment: No built-in function as such, but you can easily add `timedelta(days=7)` to skip a week.

Comment: The question marked as "duplicate" misses half of the question here.

Comment: @MarkRansom: *half*? There is no attempt by the OP here, so we can make assumptions about how much they already can do themselves. Finding the next wednesday from a given date is also a dupe. Once you have both those pieces it is trivial to put this together.

Comment: *Still* a duplicate of [Generate a list of datetimes between an interval in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10688006) The other 'half' is [Python: Find the date for the first Monday after a given a date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6558535)

Comment: @MartijnPieters The post your referenced as duplicate actually seems to do exactly what I was looking for, except for finding a specific week day from a given date, but I suppose I can find that. Thanks! I just didn't know how to word the question correctly, therefore didn't find any solutions.

Comment: Well. Now its all answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first specific weekday after a given date, just add a `timedelta` of the difference in the weekdays:

```
wed = 2 # from the datetime.weekday definition
first_wed = start + datetime.timedelta(days=(7 + wed - start.weekday()) % 7)
```

Once you have that, please see [Generate a list of datetimes between an interval in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10688006).

Comment: That part is a dupe of [Python: Find the date for the first Monday after a given a date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6558535). Really, there was no need to reopen this for that nugget.

Comment: Hrm, not sure that that deserved a downvote though (didn't vote).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you're more familiar with these questions than I am I guess. I have no problem closing this question now.