# How can l write date (1/1/1979-1/1/2015) on text

Tags: python

l would like to prepare a data set by using python. l could not find any answer for how to get date between (1/1/1979-1/1/2015).l m new python user.my start time is 1/1/1979 and end time is 1/1/2015.is there any way to get date run from start time to end time and write on txt file by keeping date format.

Comment: There are lots of dates between 1/1/1979 and 1/1/2015; which one do you want? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688006/generate-a-list-of-datetimes-between-an-interval

Comment: Due to my poor english ,my explanation could not be clear enough. l would like to get 41 years dates data between 1/1/1979 and 1/1/2015.