# Dividing the data timeline into subset of date ranges of dictioanries in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am converting date timeline into smaller date time segments based on the frequency in minutes from start time to end time.
Input:

```
start_time = '2022-11-20-09:48:00'
last_time = '2022-11-20-08:48:00'
frequency = 300 # seconds so it is 5 minutes
```

what I tried so far

```
from datetime import datetime

def time_divider(s_time, e_time, frequency):
    st_obj = datetime.strptime(s_time, '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
    start_range = st_obj.timestamp()
    end_range = datetime.strptime(e_time, '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S').timestamp()
    date_segments = []
    a = int(start_range)
    b = int(end_range+1)
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        date_segments.append({datetime.fromtimestamp(i):  datetime.fromtimestamp(i + frequency)})
        i = i + frequency
    return date_segments

date_s = time_divider(start_time, last_time, 300)
print(date_s)
```

current output:

```
[]
```

expected output and the output should come in this sequence

```
{datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 20, 9, 48): datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 20, 9, 52),datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 20, 9, 53): datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 20, 9, 57), datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 20, 9, 57): datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 20, 10, 02 ), ...}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't use something like `pandas` here, since it has the tools built in to perform these types of operations??

Comment: Would any of these solutions work for you? [Generate a list of datetimes between an interval](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10688006/13843268).

Comment: @Grismar I am developing an automation module to divide the user defined start time and end time into segments and then call the API instead of calling the whole range as there is a limit to use get an API for the specific application I am working on. So, pandas would be an extra step to do it as my main intentions was once I have the specific ranges instead of create a dictionary , I will directly call the API.

Comment: I noticed that you have given start_time and last_time, but the last_time is less than start_time so basically it would never go into the for loop. Let me know if I am correct or that is what you intended for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start_time` should be less than `end_time`

like:

`start_time = '2022-11-20-08:48:00'`

`last_time = '2022-11-20-09:48:00'`

and if we hadd `5 minutes` in `48` it would become `53` not `52` as you have mentioned in expected output.

Here is the solution which might solve the problem.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


start_time = '2022-11-20-08:48:00'
last_time = '2022-11-20-09:48:00'
frequency = 300  # seconds so it is 5 minutes


def time_divider(s_time, e_time, frequency):
    st_obj = datetime.strptime(s_time, '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
    end_range = datetime.strptime(e_time, '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
    date_segments = []
    while st_obj <= end_range:
        old_st_obj = st_obj
        st_obj = st_obj + timedelta(seconds=frequency)
        date_segments.append({old_st_obj: st_obj})
    return date_segments


date_s = time_divider(start_time, last_time, 300)
print(date_s)
```